# in chainer, how to use chainer.GradientMethod and how to customize define parameter update rule

Tags: chainer

I found a class in https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/core/generated/chainer.GradientMethod.html?highlight=gradient, it has a function called  `create_update_rule()`,  my needs is I define an Function which backward gradient, suppose I want write following code:

```
W[i] -= gradient[i] * learning_rate;
```

where W is parameter of my Function/Layer, But I don't know chainer default optimizer how to update parameter? is it `+=` or `-=` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each optimizer, for example `SGD` optimizer, is the sub class of `GradientMethod`.
And each optimizer have own `UpdateRule`.

See [SGD's update rule](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/v2.0.2/chainer/optimizers/sgd.py#L33) which calculates

`W[i] -= gradient[i] * learning_rate`